# Google Appengine OutBound traffic not going from Custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, namecheap

I am setting up a server in google app engine and i have linked a custom domain to it also I can access it from the correct URL. I use this server to issue requests to a third party payment gateway where they whitelist the domain of requests.I cant access it because my requests are not coming from the custom domain i linked to the server . 
I followed this documentation to map the custom domain
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/mapping-custom-domains

Is there an additional step to setup outgoing traffic's domain?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the outgoing networking parameters in Google App Engine.

For something like that you probably need an IaaS product.

Comment: can u suggest one

Comment: I didn't use one, but Compute Engine appears to be supporting it:  https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address